# Make interactive svg using matplotlib

Tags: python, json, matplotlib, svg, svg-animate

I saw it was possible to make an [interactive histogram with svg on the matplotlib's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/svg_histogram_sgskip.html).
Would it be possible to do this for a standard plot as for time series for example ?

Comment: Yes, totally. The example is just... an example. You can use other artists in just about the same fashion.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is. I have tried the example and it can produced interactive SVG. You may need to open it on browser.

The other way is using https://pypi.org/project/drawSvg/.